i used TradingView widget but its displays multple times on my webpage how can i fix it to display only one widget,what code can i use and where can i
The tradingview widget appears more than once.
I don't know what to do , I want it to only display one widget, not two or more.
I want it to show only one widget, but it keeps popping more widgets up on the page. What can I do to fix this? Please view the image I supplied so you can comprehend what I'm saying.
my code is here for the jsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRef } from 'react';

export const Dashboard = () => {
    const carrytrad = useRef();
        useEffect(() => {
                if (carrytrad.current) {
                    const script = document.createElement("script")
                    script.type ="text/javascript"
                    script.src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js"
                    script.async = true;
                    script.innerHTML = ` 
                        {
                            "symbols": [
                                {
                                "proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD",
                                "title": "S&P 500 Index"
                                },
                                {
                                "proName": "FOREXCOM:NSXUSD",
                                "title": "US 100 Cash CFD"
                                },
                                {
                                "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
                                "title": "EUR to USD"
                                },
                                {
                                "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
                                "title": "Bitcoin"
                                },
                                {
                                "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
                                "title": "Ethereum"
                                },
                                {
                                "description": "TSLA INC",
                                "proName": "NASDAQ:TSLA"
                                }
                            ],
                            "showSymbolLogo": true,
                            "isTransparent": false,
                            "displayMode": "adaptive",
                            "colorTheme": "white",
                            "locale": "en"
                        }`;  
                        carrytrad.current.appendChild(script);

                } else {
                    console.error("carrytrad.current is null! Check your ref initialization.");
                }
                
            }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className='home-container'>
            <div className='charts'>
                            
                <div class="tradingview-widget-container"       ref={carrytrad} >
                
                <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Track all markets on TESLA</span></a></div>
                
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className='home-container-content'>
                <div className='home-container-card'>
                </div>
                <div className='home-container-card'>
                </div>
                <div className='home-container-card'>
                </div>
                <div className='home-container-card'>
                </div>
                <div className='home-container-card'>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};



i dont have any error messages, and debugging logs
